# Matlab - change dotted line to solid

Tags: matlab, plot, line, dotted-line

How do I chage my dotted line in plot??? I know it is done like this `plot(x, y, '-')` but even if I put it in there I get dotted line

```
naj_cas = 0;
uhol_deg = -5;
v = 20;
g = 9.80665;

while uhol_deg < 85
    uhol_deg = uhol_deg + 10;
    uhol_rad = degtorad(uhol_deg);

    for t = 0:.1:5
        x = v * t * cos(uhol_rad);
        y = v * t * sin(uhol_rad) - 0.5 * g * t^2;
        axis([0 50 0 25])
        subplot(211);
        plot(x, y)
        hold on
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you post a working code that shows your problem? This code does not run.

Comment: Create new script in matlab and run that script it will work

Comment: `degtorad` is not defined - it is from mapping toolbox.

Comment: @angainor probably `pi*uhol_deg/180`

Answer (score 2):

You are plotting individual points and not a line. These are shown as dots and any change on line properties has no effect. Try this instead:

```
t = (0:.1:5);    
while uhol_deg < 85
    uhol_deg = uhol_deg + 10;
    uhol_rad = pi*uhol_deg/180;

    x = v * t * cos(uhol_rad);
    y = v * t * sin(uhol_rad) - 0.5 * g * t.^2;
    axis([0 50 0 25])
    plot(x, y)
    hold on
end
```